# PHP_excel from iliaal

Tags: php

I'm trying to get this extension to run on my PHP 5.4 installation. https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel

I've copied both libxl.dll and php_excel.dll into my ext folder. I'm running a IIS server on server2k8.

I however get these errors when starting my PHP engine.

> [06-Feb-2015 18:51:18 Asia/Kuwait] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid
> library    (maybe not a PHP library) 'libxl.dll' in Unknown on line 0
>
> [06-Feb-2015 18:51:18 Asia/Kuwait] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
> to load  dynamic library 'C:/PHP/ext/php_excel.dll' - The specified
> module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0

I've made sure that i've downloaded the correct file from the precompiled ftp site. http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/excel/20140606/

Does anyone have any tips, on what I might do wrong here?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error? If yes please help me with this as I am also getting the same error.Thanks

Comment: @djv Any solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the "thread safe (ts)" and "none thread safe (nts)" versions of the php binaries.

Maybe you have downloaded the nts version of php_excel.dll and are trying to use it with a ts version of php.

If you do that the error `"The specified module could not be found."` is thrown.